# Connecting windows phone app to remote sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build a simple windows app that collects user information from a form. I have a database online. I am really confused about sending the form data from windows phone to the SQL server.

What I want to learn:
1)Transferring data from windows phone app to sql server 
    i)  I am confused about the overall working for this. If some JSON data is to be sent to API, then some API function stores it to the database or if there is some other method to send data collected from mobile to SQL?
    ii) What is the best option for transfering mobile data from mobile to SQL server?

I am a begineer and would really appreciate if you could explain the overall dataflow from windows phone to sql server and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

you can't directly interact with a SQL Server from a Windows Phone app. The best approach would be to create a service layer around your database which exposes all the operations you need. This service will be called from the app. The most popular technologies for doing so on the Microsoft stack are WCF and ASP.NET `Web API`. Which one you choose is up to you and depends on several factors